# Cloud run deploy failed: the user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable

Tags: python, docker, port, fastapi, google-cloud-run

I have migrated my **Flask** application to **FastApi** application and I'm trying to deploy the new fastapi application to coud run using Dockerfile but I got an error due to port Issue.

I have tried all the solutions given before on such error but nothing works, also I have try many different way to write the dockerfile but yet I had the same issue.

Last try I use [FastApi Documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/docker/) to create my docker file it didn't work also.

**My Dockerfile:**

```
# Start from the official slim Python base image.
FROM python:3.9-slim

# Set the current working directory to /code.
#This is where we'll put the requirements.txt file and the app directory.
WORKDIR /code

# Copy the file with the requirements to the /code directory.
# Copy only the file with the requirements first, not the rest of the code.
# As this file doesn't change often, Docker will detect it and use the cache for this step, enabling the cache for the next step too.
COPY ./requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt

# Install the package dependencies in the requirements file.
# The --no-cache-dir option tells pip to not save the downloaded packages locally,
# as that is only if pip was going to be run again to install the same packages,
# but that's not the case when working with containers.
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /code/requirements.txt

# As this has all the code which is what changes most frequently the Docker
# cache won't be used for this or any following steps easily
COPY ./app /code/app

# Because the program will be started at /code and inside of it is the directory ./app with your code,
# Uvicorn will be able to see and import app from app.main.
CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```

Also I have tried to config the running port in the main:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=int(os.environ.get('PORT', 8080)), log_level="info")
```

I'm deploying my application using `cloudbuild.yaml` file:

```yaml
steps:
# Build the container image
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/cog-dev/new-serving', '.']
# Push the container image to Container Registry
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['push', 'gcr.io/cog-dev/new-serving']
# Deploy container image to Cloud Run
- name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
  entrypoint: gcloud
  args: ['run', 'deploy', 'new-serving', '--image', 'gcr.io/cog-dev/new-serving', '--region', 'europe-west1', '--allow-unauthenticated', '--platform', 'managed']
# Store images in Google Artifact Registry
images:
- gcr.io/cog-dev/new-serving
```

> Most of the solutions on stackoverflow have been tried even changing the ports number

**Update:**
after following [Use Google Cloud user credentials when testing containers locally](https://medium.com/google-cloud/use-google-cloud-user-credentials-when-testing-containers-locally-acb57cd4e4da) I test the docker image locally and I get this error:

```
File "/code/./app/endpoints/campaign.py", line 11, in <module>
    from app.services.recommend_service import RecommendService
  File "/code/./app/services/recommend_service.py", line 19, in <module>
    datastore_client = datastore.Client()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore/client.py", line 301, in __init__
    super(Client, self).__init__(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/client/__init__.py", line 320, in __init__
    _ClientProjectMixin.__init__(self, project=project, credentials=credentials)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/client/__init__.py", line 271, in __init__
    raise EnvironmentError(
OSError: Project was not passed and could not be determined from the environment.
```

Comment: Have a look to Cloud logging. Be sure to install uvicorn in your dependencies.

Comment: Already installed @guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: In your local environment, the issue is normal, you haven't meta data server installed (compared to Google Cloud) and so the execution runtime is not exactly the same (you used my article for the credential, but I haven't magic stuff for metadata server..). Anyway, did you check the Cloud Logging logs about your Cloud Run deployment?

Comment: Also checked yet the same error written in the question title, what confusing me is that the Flask project deployed correctly. @guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: You should have something else. It's not in the log part of Cloud Run UI, but in Cloud Logging directly. The error mentions that you container crash. You will have the stack trace in the error logs.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here and solved it by adding `timeout-keep-alive` argument to 0:

`CMD exec uvicorn app.main:app --workers 1 --timeout-keep-alive 0 --port 8080 --host 0.0.0.0`